# Can't boot properly

Tags: boot

So here's the thing. I installed ubuntu on my pen drive, and the installation went perfectly but now when I'm starting my PC I am faced with those 3 options again: 1. install
2. try without installing

Where is the dual boot? and why isn't ubuntu starting? but it occupied the drive partitions....please help..

Comment: You create a boot-able USB then use that to install on your hard drive; or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

**You have not installed ubuntu on pen drive.** You created a live usb media that can be used as installation source (like cd/DVD) and you can try ubuntu without installing.

If you use `try ubuntu` all changes on ubuntu after reboot will be lost. This can be prevented by choosing to create a persistence usb live media.

Dualboot comes when you install ubuntu to a storage device like hard disk (not creating installation media)

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot priority Devices in BIOS. Select your Hard Disk first on which you installed ubuntu & if you have only one Hard Disk then select Hard Disk & then other devices.